# Using a Managed Bean for Authentication in JavaServer Faces Applications

Tags: jsf, authentication, servlets, jsf-2

**Objective**: Want to retrieve and store the user related info (over 5 columns in USER table) in the session when user is authenticated, so that I can use the user info at various point in time during the current session.

**Approach:** I have chosen to do this by using a managed Bean (`LoginBean.java`) for authentication in my JavaServerFaces application.  I would retrieve the user info and store them in the session in the `LoginBean.login()` method.

**Ref**: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html#glxef

**Bean Code:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {
    private String id;
    private String password;

    public LoginBean() {
        System.out.println("LoginBean() called .....");
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String login() {
        System.out.println("login() invoked .....");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(id, password);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Login failed."));
            return "error";
        }

        return "home";
    }

    public void logout() {
        System.out.println("logout() invoked .....");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.logout();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Logout failed."));
        }
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>AuthenticationUsingLoginBean</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>       
            <web-resource-name>All resources are restricted</web-resource-name> 
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>          
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>            
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Form based authentication with login bean</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel for="usernameInput">User ID:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{loginBean.id}" required="true" />
        <h:message for="usernameInput"/>
        <br />
        <h:outputLabel for="passwordInput">Password:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputSecret id="passwordInput" value="#{loginBean.password}" required="true" />
        <h:message for="passwordInput" />
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Issue**
I've started new browser window and accessed the home page (`home.xhml`).
I am redirected to `login.xhtml`, which is fine.
But, on clicking `Login` button on `login.xhtml` UI, `LoginBean.login()` method is NOT getting invoked.

**Note**
`login.xhtml` should be correct as `LoginBean.login()` method is invoked successfully when I comment out    `<login-config>` in `web.xml` file.  Obviously, I can't keep it commented as the authentication won't work as expected.

**Update**
I have the necessary `JDBCRealm` configured in my tomcat's `server.xml` file and made sure that it works fine by implementing a sample form based authentication using `j_security_check`.

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
            driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xyz"
            connectionName="root"
            connectionPassword="xxxxx"
            userTable="USER" userCredCol="PASSWORD"
            userRoleTable="USER_ROLE_MPNG" userNameCol="ID" roleNameCol="ROLE_NAME" />
```

Software used:
apache-tomcat-7.0.47
JSF 2.1 (Mojarra 2.1.6)

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login()}" />
```

mind the `()` after login. you're calling a methode not trying to getter/setter a var with the name login in LoginBean.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because you are restricting all resources in your `web.xml`. You can see your login and error pages, but that does not mean that everything surrounding it is accessible, on the contrary.

#### Solution

Add a new security constraint for public resources, like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Open Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Now, create a new sub-folder where your `login.xhtml` and `error.xhtml` are and call it `public`, as in the security constraint. Move your `login.xhtml` and `error.xhtml` into the newly created folder and adjust the login configuration in your `web.xml` accordingly.